# How to search this input in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

I can have below input in my jsp file

pattern1 :-
startMartytestingReisEnding

Pattern2 :-
startMartytesting
sometextReisEnding

Pattern3 :-
startMartytesting

some inbetween lines

sometextReisEnding

I want to search it in all JSP files. I tried

```
   *Marty*\\n*Reis*
```

but its not working.How can i search it ?